# MongoDb C# driver, property of type implementing IList not saving

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Changed the persistence layer of my web app to MongoDb using the C# drivers from the MongoDb site. Was pleasantly surprised to find all of my tests passing... except for one class. One of its properties is a type that implements IList and for some reason it doesn't save its items.

I've built a minimal test case to illustrate. Here's the test code to create and save the parent object:

```
var fooCollection = database.GetCollection<Foo>( typeof( Foo ).Name );
var foo = new Foo {Id = "Root"};
foo.Foos.Add( new Foo{ Id = "Child" } );
fooCollection.Save( foo );
```

If I declare Foo.Foos as being `List<Foo>` it works:

```
public class Foo {
  public Foo() {
    Foos = new List<Foo>();
  }
  public List<Foo> Foos;
  public string Id;
}
```

The (correct) result:

```
{ "_id" : "root", "Foos" : [ { "Foos" : [], "_id" : "child" } ] }
```

However what I need is this:

```
public class Foo {
  public Foo() {
    Foos = new FooList();
  }
  public FooList Foos;
  public string Id;
}

public class FooList : IList<Foo> {
   //IList implementation omitted for brevity
}
```

The (incorrect) result is:

```
{ "_id" : "root", "Foos" : { "Capacity" : 4 } }
```

Note that it has nothing to do with my IList implementation as the results are the same if I use `FooList : List<Foo>`.

I'm presuming that the BSON serializer is getting confused? I looked at the documentation on discriminators, which led me to think that this might help:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<List<Foo>>( cm => {
  cm.AutoMap();
  cm.SetIsRootClass( true );
} );
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<FooList>();
```

I still don't get my items saved though, ends up looking like this:

```
{ "_id" : "root", "Foos" : { "_t" : [ "List`1", "FooList" ], "Capacity" : 4 } }
```

How can I save `FooList` correctly?

Comment: Have you tried adding any `BsonKnownType` attributes?

Comment: Hi there. Unless I've got it wrong, the RegisterClassMap code I listed above is equivalent to using the BsonKnownType attributes: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial#CSharpDriverSerializationTutorial-Scalarandhierarchicaldiscriminators

Comment: For anyone interested in this problem, we're nutting it out in the mongodb-user Google Group... still no luck, will post back here if I find a solution. http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/4924584946d3b7d1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am able to reproduce what you are
>   describing with 0.9, but it is working
>   correctly with the latest code.
>
> You could build the driver yourself
>   from the latest code in github, or
>   wait for 0.11 which is coming it very
>   soon.

-- Robert Stam, on the [monodb-user Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/4924584946d3b7d1)